# General advice on tackling Olympiad level maths

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Firstly, a bit of context: I am studying for a college entrance exam, which is mainly maths at the olympiad level. I am completely new to this kind of maths. Due to circumstances outside of my control, I was unable to make time to seriously study for this exam until now, and there are two weeks remaining for the exam.

Realistically speaking, I do not think I can pass the exam. However, I am not too bummed out about that. I know that I have not put in the required effort, and am merely reaping the fruits of my own (inadequate)labour.

However, what I am bummed out about is the fact that I am unable to make even slight progress into this olympiad level maths. Most of the books I read for olympiad preparation, I am not even able to understand due to the mathematical terminology which I have never been exposed to. The highest level of math I have completed is at the A-Level, which I had done pretty well at, both Mathematics and Further Mathematics. But I am at a profound loss when it comes to Olympiad level math.

Background about the institute: It is a mathematical institute. The questions in this exam are often compared to the nation olympiads in my country, by the people who have taken the exam, and the college offers direct admission to olympiad candidates as well. Many of the preparatory books recommended by the institute itself for the purpose of clearing this exam are olympiad preparation books.

If I do understand the terminology in some less sophisticated books, I am unable to even start solving the question, as I am at a loss on how to implement the general theorems I learnt in these kind of specific cases.

For example, this question: [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYzXJ.png)

Supposedly this is the way to solve it: [Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwwG8.png)

How am I supposed to know what to 'Suppose' in the beginning? The chapter covers theorems such as the Division Algorithm and Euclid's Theorem and the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.But I am absolutely not able to connect those theorems to this question. And the answers have these 'leaps' of mathematical logic which I am not able to intuitively grasp easily, and require me looking at the question for hours, and trying to figure out what happens between steps.

My question is: **Where should someone like me, uninitiated in olympiad level maths, start? Which contest would serve as a good stepping stone to learn to tackle such problems? Any useful resources?**

Comment: Ideally, restrict yourself to one question per post.  As it is, your post needs far more focus, because there are entire books available to answer your question.  Narrow your post down to specific topics, not all of math.  You might want to check out [matheducators.se], as well.

Comment: Are you sure your "college entrance exam" has "olympiad level" questions? That would be rare. Your best plan of study is to start with actual sample exams.

Comment: Another point: while you say " I am studying for a college entrance exam, which is mainly maths at the olympiad level,"  you are confusing contest math with undergraduate preparation pre-college.  They are not equivalent.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to do math for fun and not with any exam goal in mind. Because if you truly enjoy math, you will navigate your way to learning more and more. For me, interesting math YouTube videos really helped as each one left me with more unanswered questions. And once I felt confident enough with a topic, I would patiently try to solve some hard problems. I think the moment you make the process about the goal and not the journey, it's all going to feel like an uphill battle. I don't know if this is practical for you as you probably have limited time, but just some thoughts.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah this college has a 'mathematical institute' in its name, and many people who have taken the exam quite often compare it to the national olympiads in my country, and the books suggested by the institute itself for studying for the exam are olympiad preparation books.

Comment: To answer your specific question, the solution just asks you to "suppose" that the claim in the question is false.

Comment: @amWhy Well I actually have no experience with olympiad level maths, or contest level maths. It is the people who have taken the exam who compare it to olympiad level maths, and plus the institute offers direct admission to olympiad candidates, which is one of the only exceptions to writing the exam which made me think it had similar questions.

Comment: Also, given your math experience, I do not think you should start off with IMO questions as they can be quite intimidating. Maybe work your way up from the [AMCs](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/AMC_Problems_and_Solutions).

Comment: @Not_GOd  This is crucial information to include in your post (question post), in an edit, so users save time knowing straight up what the question is.  Nonetheless, your question remains for too broad, and needs far more focused, so the question is answerable in a paragraph or two or three.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer Yes I find myself absolutely lost, and have no clue as to where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a book's worth of content that can be written to answer this question but I'll keep my advice simple and short.

**Think like a mathematician.**

Much can be said about this but I'll use an analogy Professor Terence Tao often references. A lot of mathematics is like rock-climbing $-$ it's about finding the footholes nearest to you and working your way to the top of the mountain. Hence, when you are faced with a challenging problem, think not of the final destination but the subtle hints and clues in the problem $-$ what do they reveal? A large part of doing this successfully is building mathematical intuition. I recommend going through solutions to Olympiad problems and noting the common approaches you come across. For example, for many questions on probability, [casework](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Casework) is used.

Recommended resource:
[Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking)

**Learning concepts**

A large part of learning a concept well is being able to reproduce and apply it in a variety of situations $-$ it is not just learning some formulae. This comes from pondering, revisiting and questioning what you have learnt. Importantly, you need to ask the question Why?. There is no exhaustive list of math topics I can provide you but the following have good summaries of pertinent Olympiad level topics.

[The Book of Mathematical Formulas and Strategies](https://www.omegalearn.org/thebookofformulas)

[AIME Math Contest Preparation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/aime-math-contest-preparation/)

Remember, simply reading and understanding the concepts in the above links is not enough. You need to actively reflect on them. Once you think you have a strong grasp on it, solve problems. [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) has a good collection of questions and you can navigate through questions from different Olympiads using help from these [Competition rating](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/AoPS_Wiki:Competition_ratings) guidelines.

**Enjoy.**

It's so easy to get lost in this messy process of moving from one topic to another. Try to take some time to appreciate the beauty of what you are learning and you will feel much more comfortable. For me, YouTube videos were a big source of inspiration. [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/c/3blue1brown) is one channel I highly recommend. After all, the journey matters the most, not the end result.

I wish you success in your short-term and long-term mathematical endeavours.

Just keep swimming! ${\cdot}\kern -4pt {\subset}\kern -3pt {\rtimes}$